# load node in a tree extjs 3 by clicking on the arrow

Tags: java, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I have created a tree that appends the child node to a tree node when the node is clicked.
Initially while loading the tree I added a dummy child node to each node so that a folder icon and the arrow is visible alongside the node to indicate that it has some child nodes, when a user clicks the node the dummy child is replaced by the nodes returned by the call of the load function

I used the following code to append child node to a tree node

```
 listeners: {
   'render': function(tp){

            tp.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', function(tree, node){

            tp.getLoader().dataUrl = '/zport/clusterSysReg?args='+node.attributes.name;
            tp.getLoader().load(node);
            ...................... 
            ......................
            }
}
```

Every thing is working fine till now, but adding a dummy nodes creates a problem -- when a user click on the arrow the node gets expanded and user sees the dummy node. The default behavior of the arrow is to expand the node. Can this behavior be modified so that when user clicks the arrow the **load(node)** function get called and user can see the actual child nodes of a tree node

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out ........ call the **load(node)** function in **'beforeexpandnode'** event
like this ............

```
listeners: {
    'beforeexpandnode' : function(node,event){
         tree.getLoader().dataUrl = '/zport/clusterSysReg?args='+node.attributes.name;
         tree.getLoader().load(node);
         ..................
         ....................
     }
},
```